# How to check if a given filter exists in the filter's collection of the store?

Tags: extjs4.2

I have something like:

```
if (store.filters.contains('FilterByCountry')) {
     store.removeFilter('FilterByCountry');
};
```

where previously i created the filter and added it to the filter collection for that store:

```
filterByCountry = new Ext.util.Filter({
                filterFn: function(record) {
                    return (record.get('isDefault') === true) ||    (Ext.Array.contains(record.get('assignedCountries'), countryId));
                },
                id: 'FilterByCountry'
            });
            store.addFilter(filterByCountry);
```

All is fine, i can look into the filters collection and i see the filter i added having the id 'FilterByCountry'
But the

```
if (store.filters.contains('FilterByCountry')) {
         store.removeFilter('FilterByCountry');
    };
```

is always false. How can I test for the existence of a filter into the filters collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: i have to use store.filters.containsKey(filterId). It works